# How to "extract" those lines from the background?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, background-removal

I have a fairly simple image, with a few blurred lines:

[image]

I would like to export these lines from the background: I need either black or transparent (preferred) background, and those lines I'd need some purple color matching the feel to the original one.

Similar like this (but of course without the background):

[image]

The final background will be black (independently of the image itself), so I would like to make sure these lines will look nice on a black background.

I've tried using the *Magic Wand tool* but it fails on those "needle" shapes. I've also tried with  *Select > Color ranges*, but with that, either the lines are cut or the background "comes" too close to the lines (in color).

How can I reach my goal in Photoshop?

Comment: Is this a placeholder for your actual need? Why would you not just redraw this in something like illustrator or inkscape?

Comment: This is my actual need. Redrawing seems feasible, but I don't really know how to proceed with that (I don't have Illustrator, only InkScape).

Comment: @Daniel - just copy and paste the image into Inkscape. Using the image as a guide, draw the shapes with the Bézier tool. no stroke, set the fill colour to whatever you want. Then delete the raster image once you have finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The versions you have attached have far too low resolution to show the narrow parts as sharp. Scale the image to 400%, select one part at a time with the polygonal lasso tool, copy and paste it to a new layer. An example (rotated 90 degrees to save space):

[image]

The originals (=Layer 1) are closed to show the pasted result. You can also fill the selection with a new color. Have Anti-aliasing ON to avoid jagginess.

When you have the parts in separate layers you can select them easily. Only click the image icon in the Layers panel by holding the Ctrl key at the same time.

Essentially this is the same as drawing with the bezier curve tool in Inkscape - only click at the corners. You can as well draw with the Pen in Photoshop - learn, how to make filled shapes this way.

As I said, in Photoshop the resolution must be high enough to show the thin ends. I scaled your image to 400%.